# How to read .arff file with R?

Tags: r, arff

Is there any way to do that?

Yes, i'm new to R.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`read.arff` in package `foreign` reads data from Weka Attribute-Relation File Format (ARFF) files.

**Update**: there is a new package on CRAN:

[farff](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/farff/index.html): A Faster 'ARFF' File Reader and Writer

Answer (score 26):

In general the answer to questions like this can be found via the `sos` package, which accesses a full-text search of all the packages on CRAN.

```
install.packages("sos")
library("sos")
findFn("arff")
```

finds functions in the `foreign` (as noted above) and `RWeka` packages.  Since `foreign` is a recommended package, it will be installed on your system by default. Hence you would have found the answer with

```
help.search("arff")
```

in the first place, without installing the `sos` package.  `sos` is still worth having for times when the string you are searching for isn't in the metadata (title, keywords, alias, etc.), which is all that `help.search` searches, or not in a package you already have installed on your system (ditto).  (Looking through the [R Data Import/Export Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf), which also comes with your system, is generally useful but would *not* have found the answer to this question ...)

It might be useful to know about the `RWeka` version on the off chance that the version in `foreign` (which you should try first) fails for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! There's not much info on R in Google.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin Yes there is.  Search for "[R] arff" in google and your first hit is the one you want.

Answer (score 10):

Even though this question is already answered I realize there is another noteworthy solution. Check the `RWeka` package that enables you to read and write `arff` files. Plus it gives you a wrapper for `Weka` functions. So you could use Weka functionality without installing Weka itself (though it installs .jars). See also this [doku](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/RWeka.pdf) -> `read.arff`.

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about the data and not the relations, you can just use:

```
read.csv("data.arff", header=FALSE, comment.char = "@")
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do it is using the `"RWeka"` library which has `read.arff()` function that reads `.arff` files.

```
library(RWeka)
test=read.arff("../Test/test.arff")
```

Hope this helps.